Cohen proof that : Forcing has to be done using ordinals within countable models
In Cohen "Set Theory and the Continuum Hypothesis" on page 110 says :
Our last theorem shows we must consider countable models. And then goes on to say :
M is a fixed countable model of ZF which we take for definiteness as the minimal model. Then V=L holds in M. Our first goal is to see what other standard models we have any hope of showing exist. Let $\alpha_0$ = sup{$\alpha : \alpha \in M$}. $M_\alpha$ denotes the constructible sets constructed at the $\alpha$-th stage of the construction. We then have M = $\bigcup$ $\{ M_\beta : \beta \lt \alpha_0 \}$. Further assume the consistency of ZF + SM since the theorem uses the minimum model.
THEOREM. It is consistent to assume that for no $\alpha \gt \alpha_0$ is $\bigcup$ $\{ M_\beta : \beta \lt \alpha \}$ a model for ZF.
Proof : If for all $\alpha \gt \alpha_0, \text{  } \bigcup$ $\{ M_\beta : \beta \lt \alpha \}$ is not a model of ZF then we are done. If not, let $\alpha_1$ denote the least ordinal for which it is a model and put N = $\bigcup$ $\{ M_\beta : \beta \lt \alpha_1 \}$. Then clearly in N it is true that $\alpha \gt \alpha_0 \implies M_\alpha$ is not a model for ZF and the theorem is proved.
COROLLARY : It is consistent to assume that for any model N, $\alpha_0$ = sup{$\alpha : \alpha \in N$}.
And then Cohen goes on to say : "Thus, whatever new model N we construct, we must make do with the ordinals in M and our only hope is to construct N by 'broadening' M by introducing new sets of rank $\alpha$ where $\alpha < \alpha_0$.
Question : It looks like some steps in the proof have been omitted or some other background knowledge is being assumed. The "Then clearly ..." does not seem to lead to the theorem, since what is being assumed between $\alpha_0$ and $\alpha_1$ (if there is anything) and above $\alpha_1$ and why ? Is it possible to provide a more explanatory proof, as I am just guessing otherwise ?

I don't think what you have put into brackets is a correct interpretation of what Cohen is saying. "Our last theorem" is the previous theorem, not the next one. The one that says it's consistent that every uncountable transitive model of ZFC satisfies CH.

@spaceisdarkgreen. Yes you are correct. I have edited the text.

I will use the standard modern notation and definition of the constructible hierarchy (Cohen's definitions are a bit different):
$$\begin{gather}L_0 = 0,\\L_{\alpha+1}= \operatorname{Def}(L_\alpha),\\L_\lambda = \bigcup_{\alpha < \lambda}L_\alpha,\end{gather}$$ where Def is the definable power set. And $L= \bigcup_\alpha L_\alpha.$
Also note that if there is a transitive $M\models \sf ZF$ with height $\alpha,$ then $L_\alpha\models \sf ZFC,$ so the heights of transitive models of $\sf ZF$ are just given by the $\alpha$ such that $L_\alpha\models \sf ZFC.$
The theorem/corollary Cohen states can be rephrased "it is consistent with $\sf ZF + SM$ that every transitive model of $\sf ZF$ is of the same height as the minimal model." Returning to his argument, in $\sf ZF + SM$, define $\alpha_0$ as the least height of a transitive model. In the unlikely event that $\sf ZF + SM$ proves that $\alpha_0$ is the only ordinal such that $L_{\alpha_0}\models \sf ZFC,$ then we're done. If not, then we can assume there is a model $\sf ZF + SM$ where it holds that there is a second least ordinal $\alpha_1$ where $L_{\alpha_1}\models \sf ZFC.$ But then, if we look at that model's $L_{\alpha_1},$ by absoluteness, $\alpha_0$ is only ordinal in $L_{\alpha_1}$ such that $L_{\alpha_1}$ thinks $L_{\alpha_0}\models \sf ZFC.$ So that model's $L_{\alpha_1}$ is a model of $\sf ZF + SM$ in which there is no transitive model of $\sf ZF$ with height $>\alpha_0.$
You ask about what happens above $\alpha_1,$ but the point is that $L_{\alpha_1}$ only sees models with height below $\alpha_1,$ so it doesn't matter if there are any models with height greater than $\alpha_1.$ That's why we cut it off there.

Nice. So to check I have understood, is the point of the proof that there is at least one model N=$L_{\alpha_1}$ that thinks there is no transitive model of ZF with height > $\alpha_0$. Since we can't ever know what this ordinal is, it is pointless trying to create a new model N with $\alpha \gt \alpha_0$ in which to create a new set G that tests CH etc. since we could be unlucky and pick $\alpha_1$. continued ...

So if, within N, the new set G requires the use of an $\alpha \gt \alpha_0$ in its construction, then G would potentially be using constructions that N thinks do not satisfy ZF. To avoid being unlucky, we play safe and stick with $L_{\alpha_0}$.

Also I was wondering what you meant by "If not, we can assume we're in a model" .... is this in the metatheory ?

@Confusdius The point is motivational mainly. Cohen wants to only assume ZF + SM and show there are transitive models of ZFC + not CH, etc, and this theorem says it is pointless to try to look for any models that aren't of minimal height since ZF + SM can't prove they exist. Thus the most sensible approach is to try to look for extensions of the minimal model with the same height.

@Confusdius Regarding your second question, I edited to (hopefully) clarify that part.

@Confusdius (On a side note, if the goal is simply to learn forcing, I’d recommend a more modern book like Kunen. Much of this book holds up, but Cohen’s approach to forcing is outdated.)

@Confusdius another more formalistic way to structure the argument is if ZF+SM proved $\alpha_1$ exists (i.e. there is a height of a transitive model other than the minimal one), then it would prove ZF+SM proves $\alpha_1$ exists and hence prove $\alpha_1$ exists in $L_{\alpha_1}$ (since that’s a model of ZF + SM), which we’ve seen is also easily disproven, so ZF+SM would be inconsistent.

So is it correct to view Cohen's Theorem as an independence result ?  If ZF+SM is consistent then it can't prove that any model for ZF + SM exists. By the upward Lowenheim Skolem theorem there can be models of ZF + SM of any cardinality. So the first part of Cohen Theorem can not be proved or ZF+SM would be inconsistent (i.e. : "If for all $\alpha \gt \alpha_0, \text{  } \bigcup$ ${ M_\beta : \beta \lt \alpha }$ is not a model of ZF then we are done" can't be proved in ZF+SM). continued ...

As ZF+SM also can't prove $\alpha_1$ exists, then it is independent of ZF+SM whether there is a model with ordinal greater than $\alpha_0$.

@Confusdius It is independent in the same sense that Con(ZF) is independent of ZF. Which is to say, it's presumably independent, but one of the directions is strictly higher consistency strength. We can't prove Con(ZF+SM) implies Con(ZF+SM+ $\alpha_1$ exists) (other than in the case that we adopt axioms that imply Con(ZF+SM+ $\alpha_1$ exists))  but we can prove Con(ZF+SM) implies Con(ZF+SM+ $\alpha_1$ does not exist), or to put in another way, we can't rule out, other than by adopting stronger axioms, that ZF+SM is consistent and proves $\alpha_1$ does not exist.

@Confusdius I don't understand the part about the upward Lowenheim Skolem theorem. I don't believe it's relevant, but I don't understand what argument you're making. I would note that while it implies that if there is a model of ZF + SM, there are models of arbitrarily large cardinality, it says nothing about the existence of transitive models. (Even if transitive models exist... elementary extensions of transitive models aren't necessarily well-founded.)
